# Get multiple url Firebase storage for single ID

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Someone has some idea of how to get the urls of the files I'm uploading to Firebase Storage for a single ID in Realtime Database. In other words, I have a form and I generate an object with different fields, inside of them everything is fine but I would like it to have a field of images and within it are the urls of the images that I have uploaded.

Something like that:

```
ID {
descripcion: "Descripción 1",
destacado: "Destacado 1",
images: {
  imageID1: "imageUrl1",
  imageID2: "imageUrl2",
  imageID3: "imageUrl3"
},
titulo: "Titulo 1"
}
```

So far I have managed to upload multiple images but I generate the IDs separately:
[image: get multiple url]

Another minor problem is that it does not generate the other fields, but I hope to solve it later. If you have any better idea of how to raise this, any help is welcome.

```
addProyecto(proyecto: Proyecto) {
let key = this.db.list('proyectos').push(proyecto).key;
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
storageRef.child(`${this.basePath}/${proyecto.file.name}`).put(proyecto.file)

  .then(
  snapshot => {
    let titulo = proyecto.titulo
    proyecto.images = [
      snapshot.downloadURL,
    ]
    this.db.object('proyectos/' + key).set(proyecto);
  }

);
}
```

Comment: In `let key = this.db.list('proyectos').push(proyecto).key;` you're calling `push`, which will create a new push ID each time. You'll need to call it once and keep track of the key if you want to keep other data under it.

Comment: @JenPerson thanks. How can I call it once? If you have time I would appreciate that you can look at this stackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/firebase-multiple-upload-single-id?embed=1&file=app/crear-proyecto/crear-proyecto.component.ts